# Allow users to upload all filetypes safely

Tags: php, html

I want to allow my users to upload all filetypes because all the files have to be checked manually anyway. 
Is it safe to zip all the files on upload so for example nothing can be executed on the server? And later manually unzip and check the files? Or is there another designated way for this?

Comment: What do you mean with not executed? Even if a user submits a program, the server will not execute that program automatically...

Comment: there are many ways to do that? First show us what have you tried?

Comment: Upload to a non web accecable folder, so they cant be accessed from an external source

Comment: Just... don't do anything with the files. Put them somewhere nobody (except you) has access to them, done.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the files afterwards? Also make sure the directory is unknown for the people who will upload files so they can't place scripts and run them. Another idea is stripping all the files of their rights so they can't execute anything.

Comment: @TomKriek I want to check te files manually and forward them to someone else for processing of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not say this is "safe" for example, if someone manage it to inject code they could also use PHPs Zip utility (If installed!) to extract it and then include it to execute it (or use exec if not a php file).

I think you should more care about your overall-security to prevent code injection and block this directory with an .htaccess file.

Comment: I know, but I was too lazy :(

Comment: I think this was the answer I was searching for. Didn't think of it like this where someone could unzip and execute the files. So simply said you guys would recommend to place the files in a folder outside the webroot and prevent direct access?

Comment: Yup I would recommend to do so.